# Bean to monitor a topic and give statistics in a portlet?

Tags: java, javabeans, liferay, publish-subscribe, java-ee-5

I'm new to java and i'm not sure how to implement the following.

We have a topic queue where some java apps write various object messages to (Performance with Min,max and avg processing times/Error/debug logging). What i need to do is get these messages from the queue and have them displayed on a portlet (in liferay 5.2) with icefaces (1.8.2) and push notifications as either a graph or just the values. But i'm not sure how to implement the bean to accomplish this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Winston